The use of genitive forms
I've come across to the task where I'm supposed to put the apostrophe s or the of-phrase (sometimes 2 variants are possible) and I can't make up my mind whether I did the task right or not. I'd also like to read the explanations you can provide.
Here are the sentences

What did you do by the end of the course? What did you do by the course's end?
Barcelona's architecture is a constant source of inspiration. The architecture of Barcelona is a constant source of inspiration.
The scientists were surprised by the virus's ability to mutate. The scientists were surprised by the ability of the virus to mutate.

I'll be very happy if you correct my mistakes and explain them.

Since you give both versions, it's not clear what 'mistakes' you may have made. Personally, I would prefer the 'of' version for all three.

There are loads of existing questions very similar to these. Look at the possessives and of-genitive tag and search saxon genitive.

(1) almost (but not quite) demands the Norman genitive (periphrastic 'of') as the Saxon genitive ('s) sounds too lightweight, informal. With (2), I'd use Saxon one day, Norman the next. I prefer the Saxon genitive with (3) to avoid the mouthful 'surprised by the ability of the virus to mutate'. For some reason, it doesn't sound too lightweight.

I think Edwin’s comment is a worthy addition to the various answers to similar questions, as it’s the only place the Norman genitive is clearly compared to the Saxon. @EdwinAshworth

It is a general weakness of ELU that there’s no systematic way to refer to the duplicates or near-duplicates of basic questions, and thus questions get closed without even a cross-reference.

@Xanne Cerberus's answer at Why are some possessives formed with 'of' but not apostrophe-s? gives a very in-depth comparison of the Norman & Saxon 'genitives'. I've added this question and my response as an answer there, as semantics but not pragmatics seem to be addressed in other answers.

None of these six possibilities is actually wrong. Some of them may be somewhat more idiomatic than others, but take a look at this Ngram — the architecture of London and London's architecture are almost equally common today.

On the other hand, the end of the course is a lot more common than the course's end.
